# Merge dataframes by a match in at least one of two columns

Tags: r, merge

I've been searching for a solution and have been experimenting, but I can't seem to perform what I should be a simple task.

I have two data frames formatted similar to the below toy examples

```
DF1 = data.frame(A=c("cats","dogs",NA,"dogs"), B=c("kittens","puppies","kittens",NA), C=c(88,99,101,110))

    A       B           C
1   cats    kittens     88
2   dogs    puppies     99
3   NA      kittens     101
4   dogs    NA          110


DF2 = data.frame(D=c(1,2), A=c("cats","dogs"), B=c("kittens","puppies"))

    D   A       B
1   1   cats    kittens
2   2   dogs    puppies
```

I wish to merge the two data sets such that the output is:

```
      A     B         C     D
1   cats    kittens   88    1
2   dogs    puppies   99    2
3   dogs    NA        110   2
4     NA    kittens   101   1
```

In other words, any rows with labels A=="cats" or B=="kittens" will be mapped to 1 in the column D, any rows with A=="dogs" or B=="puppies" will be  mapped to 2.

I have used the command

```
merge(DF1, DF2, by=c("A","B"), all.x=TRUE)
```

However this not match rows 3 and 4 correctly, only rows 1 and 2. I get the output

```
      A     B         C     D
1   cats    kittens   88    1
2   dogs    puppies   99    2
3   dogs    NA        110   NA
4     NA    kittens   101   NA
```

Please note the actual datasets I'm working with are very long. In reality DF1 is over 1,000,000 rows and DF2 is over 300,000 rows  thousands of rows each, so a solution that could be scaled is what I really need.

Comment: You've come quite far with your example. Care to make it more handy to copy/paste into R? Here are some tips on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Your example output doesn't match your description. Shouldn't column "D" be `c(1, 2, 2, 1)`?

Comment: You're entirely correct, I've amended this to avoid confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different approach:

```
library(functional)

partial.merge <- function(DF1, DF2) {
  common.cols <- intersect(names(DF1), names(DF2))
  result.col <- names(DF2)[!(names(DF2) %in% common.cols)]

  # This can only handle one result column:
  stopifnot(length(result.col) == 1)

  # Merge in each common column, one at a time.
  # The identical operation is done for each common column, so Reduce is useful:
  r <- Reduce(function(D, C) merge(D, DF2[c(C, result.col)], by=c(C), all.x=TRUE), x=common.cols, init=DF1)

  # The merge created cols like c('D.x', 'D.y').  These are the columns:
  merge.cols <- paste(result.col, c('x', 'y'), sep='.')

  # The .x and .y columns are partial, put them together:
  r[[result.col]] <- rowMeans(r[merge.cols], na.rm=TRUE)

  # Remove the temporaries:
  for (i in merge.cols) {
    r[[i]] <- NULL
  }
  return(r)
}

partial.merge(DF1, DF2)
##         B    A   C D
## 1 kittens cats  88 1
## 2 kittens <NA> 101 1
## 3 puppies dogs  99 2
## 4    <NA> dogs 110 2
```

Comment: While I don't mind if you select my answer as correct, I suggest that you actually try these on your real data and check the run time with `system.time()`.  This is almost certainly the slowest of the three!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can try something along these lines:

```
temp <- merge(DF1, DF2, by=c("A","B"), all.x=TRUE)

within(temp, {
  M1 <- c("cats", "kittens")
  D <- ifelse(A %in% M1 | B %in% M1, 1, 2)
  rm(M1)
})
#      A       B   C D
# 1 cats kittens  88 1
# 2 dogs puppies  99 2
# 3 dogs    <NA> 110 2
# 4 <NA> kittens 101 1
```

You can nest `ifelse` statements if you need more than just these two options.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for the toy example but my original datasets are very long (there are thousands of different pairs). Is there a solution that would work for really large dataframes ?

Answer (score 2):

```
DF1[which(DF1$A=="cats"|DF1$B=="kittens"), "D"] <- DF2[which(DF2$A=="cats"|DF2$B=="kittens"), "D"]
DF1[which(DF1$A=="dogs"|DF1$B=="puppies"), "D"] <- DF2[which(DF2$A=="dogs"|DF2$B=="puppies"), "D"]
DF1
#-------
     A       B   C D
1 cats kittens  88 1
2 dogs puppies  99 2
3 <NA> kittens 101 1
4 dogs    <NA> 110 2
```

Functionalized:

```
idxpick <- function(a,b) DF1[which(DF1$A==a|DF1$B==b), "D"] <<- # Yes, I feel guilty.
                                   DF2[which(DF2$A==a|DF2$B==b), "D"]
DF1 = data.frame(A=c("cats","dogs",NA,"dogs"), 
                 B=c("kittens","puppies","kittens",NA), 
                 C=c(88,99,101,110))
DF2 = data.frame(D=c(1,2), A=c("cats","dogs"), B=c("kittens","puppies"))
apply(DF2, 1, function(rr) idxpick(rr["A"], rr["B"]) )
#------------
[1] 1 2

DF1
     A       B   C D
1 cats kittens  88 1
2 dogs puppies  99 2
3 <NA> kittens 101 1
4 dogs    <NA> 110 2
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution. Sorry but I should've been more clear that the datasets I'm working with are very very large so writing a command for every possible pair isn't really feasible. There's about 300,000 different types of pairs.

Comment: Might be possible to make this into a function that could be `apply`-ed to DF2. It will take a long time. Might need to leave running overnight.

Comment: A rare `<<-` spotted in the wild, neat.

Comment: I can probably get rid of it with an eval-substitute backflip. I know where to look for some examples but I'm feeling lazy.

Comment: Thanks, that code works great for the example I posted. I'm having a little trouble modifying it to work on another example where there's more than two different pairs. See the example I posted in the edit above.

Once I've worked that out, I can mark this as correct. Cheers :)

Comment: Well thanks a lot. I solve teh problem that was posed and it works great, but you won't mark it correct until I solve another problem that wasn't posed?

Comment: Sorry, maybe my original question wasn't clear enough. I'll mark your answer as correct as leave it for now.